# MongoDB auto reconnect with docker + node.js + mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

In one container (container1) I have a running mongod daemon. This container is linked to another container with node.js (container2).

When I start containers everything works fine:

```
docker start container1
docker start container2
```

When I restart container1, the node.js script in the second container loses it's connection to mongodb and can't reconnect since the IP of the mongodb changed.

How can I configure node.js to reconnect using new IP of the mongodb server?

**Update**: Simplified code, that stops working after container1 is restarted:

```
var http = require('http')
  , mongodb = require('mongodb');

mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://username:password@container1:27017/dbname', {uri_decode_auth: true, server: {auto_reconnect: true}}, function(err, db) {
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        // Do some work with db and send response
    }).listen(config.port);
});
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to either A. Don't change the IP address and assign static IP's B. Use DNS resolvable host names rather than IP addresses. That is a lot easier than trying to figure out the required message passing needed to reset a connection.

Comment: I don't use the IP address, the connection string looks like mongodb://username:password@container1:27017/dbname

Comment: But where are you defining those host names? For me, the connection is just re-etablished with the server at the new IP address it resolves to.

Comment: Updated question with some code. After the container1 is restarted, the db object is useless.

Comment: As I have already stated, the code does not matter here. Are your containers set up to update a central DNS on restart? If you are not doing something like what is outlined in [this article](http://wiredcraft.com/blog/dns-and-docker-containers/) then it is your configuration that is at fault. Not the program or driver.